# If $\int_1^\infty|f(x)|dx$ converges then $\int_1^\infty (f(x)\cos x)dx$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Prove or disprove: If $\int_1^\infty|f(x)|dx$ converges then $\int_1^\infty (f(x)\cos x)dx$ converges.
I was trying to find counterexamples and I couldn't find any, so I moved to try proving it.
I know that if $\int_1^\infty|f(x)|dx$ converges then $\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$ converges, and I also know that $\int_1^\infty\cos xdx$ diverges, but I couldn't get much out of it.
Can I get a lead?

Comment: A function is Riemann integrable iff it is bounded and it is continuous almost everywhere. Because the first integrable converges we know this is true for $|f(x)|.$ Can you use this knowledge to infer the same for $f(x)\cos(x)$?

Comment: @StephenDonovan So if $|()|$ is integrable then $f()$ is integrable, and since $cos()$ is integrable then $f(x)cosx $is integrable?
And since $f(x)cosx$ is integrable it is bounded, and therefore it has a limit?

Comment: Is $*$ multiplication or convolution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\lvert\cos x\rvert \le 1$, note that $\lvert f(x)\cdot\cos(x) \rvert\le \lvert f(x)\rvert$. By the [direct comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test#For_integrals)
$$\int_1^\infty\lvert f(x)\cdot\cos(x) \rvert\,\mathrm{d}x\le \int_1^\infty|f(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x .$$
We know that the second integral converges. Since the first one is less or equal to the latter integral, it converges too.

As you stated correctly: "If $\int_1^\infty|g(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x$ converges then $\int_1^\infty g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ converges".

Applying this for $g(x)=f(x)\cdot\cos(x)$ gives us the desired statement that $\int_1^\infty f(x)\cdot\cos(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$ converges too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that $|\cos(x)|\leq 1$ from which you deduce that $|f(x)\cos(x)|\leq |f(x)|$. Can you conclude from there?

Comment: Please read other answers before you post one.

Comment: Yes, and check your $\leq$ sign before posting...

Comment: I deleted my answer in less than 1 minute after posting to edit it. I believe everyone is allowed to make typos -I'm a human. Posting the same answer after $4$ minutes instead of upvoting/downvoting or leaving it is not a typo or a small mistake. I'm not saying this to gain more rep (many users know me and can verify that) etc., please read other answer before posting one yorself under *every* post in the future.

Answer (score 0):

My approach :
$$-1 \le |cosx| \le 1$$
So, $$ -f(x) \le f(x)cosx \le f(x) $$
Now, $$f(x) \le |f(x)|$$
So, $$-|f(x)| \le f(x)cosx \le |f(x)|$$
Thus, $$\int_1^\infty -|f(x)|dx \le \int_1^\infty f(x)cosxdx \le \int_1^\infty |f(x)|dx$$
As $$\int_1^\infty |f(x)|dx$$ converges,
Hence, $$\int_1^\infty f(x)cosxdx$$ also converges by comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

basically:
$$|\cos x|\le1$$
and since:
$$f(x)\cos(x)\le|f(x)\cos(x)|=|f(x)||\cos(x)|\le |f(x)|$$
now integrate and you get:
$$\int f(x)\cos(x)\,dx\le \int|f(x)|\,dx$$